# Selenium WaitDriver doesn't wait for element to be clickable

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium-webdriver

When I click on a button it displays me a form with another buttons and I want to click on one of them. Here is a video with this (really short one), please watch http://screencast.com/t/zyliSemW1s1

So I click on button "Buy Tickets" simply like that:

```
button.Click();
```

And then I wait for the next button to be clickable.

**I use the next code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(myButton));
```

After that I click on button that I waited for:

```
element.Click();
```

And I get error: Element is not clickable at that point.

As I know, the method ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable() waits for 2 conditions: element is visible and element is enabled.

When I use Thread.Sleep(3000) before clicking on the second button the code works and button is clickable.

I saw similar issue and the solution was to wait for handlers of this button:[Selenium Wait doesn't wait for Element to be Clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614205/)

But what to do if I don't know what handles it? I think it handles by jQuery and I use the next code to wait till it stops executing:

```
var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
```

If it returns "false" I wait and check again.

But it still doesn't work.

**So for now my flow goes like that:**

1. I click on button "Buy Tickets"
2. I wait till jQuery stops executing
3. I wait till element is clickable using ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable() method
4. I click on the element and it returns me an error that it is not clickable.

**Please guys tell me what is wrong in my flow and how to manage it correct.**

**Update**: 
I'm adding HTML code of buttons:

I click to this one:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning play-now" name="button" type="submit">Buy Tickets</button>
```

And wait for this one:

```
<img alt="Credit Card" class="merchant" src="https://numgames-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/merchant/image/21/CC_Offline.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ2Q64HPERGHAJJUA&amp;Expires=1470984765&amp;Signature=Qj%2BFSQ3ElctkY6KTMfzp%2FedPjPo%3D">
```

Comment: Can you increase this to 30? `WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));` and then try.

Comment: Sure I tried it. It doesn't work. In fact I need like 1-2 seconds till it's done. But it doesn't wait it...

Comment: I see then you should not use this method : ElementToBeClickable

Comment: denis, I'll add a few extension methods that i use to naviagte these choppy waters in scenarios similar to your own. please note, these may not form an answer, merely a springboard to get you over the hurdle

Comment: Are you able to share the html for the buttons?

Comment: I'll add it to the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Denis,

As mentioned in comments to OP, here are a few little extension methods that may help your quest:

```
public static void WaitForAjax(this IWebDriver driver, int timeoutSecs = 10, bool throwException = false)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < (timeoutSecs*10); i++)
    {
        var javaScriptExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        var ajaxIsComplete = javaScriptExecutor != null && (bool)javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        if (ajaxIsComplete) return;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    if (throwException)
    {
        throw new Exception("WebDriver timed out waiting for AJAX call to complete");
    }
}

public static bool ElementExists(this IWebDriver driver, By condition)
{
    return ElementExists(driver, condition, new TimeSpan());
}

public static bool ElementExists(this IWebDriver driver, By condition, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    bool isElementPresent = false;

    if (timeSpan == default(TimeSpan))
    {
        timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000);
    }

    var driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, (TimeSpan)timeSpan);
    driverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));
    isElementPresent = driverWait.Until(x => x.FindElements(condition).Any());

    return isElementPresent;
}

public static IWebElement FindElementAfterWait(this IWebDriver driver, By condition, int fromSeconds = 90)
{
    bool isElementPresent = false;
    IWebElement singleElement = null;

    var driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(fromSeconds));
    driverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));

    try
    {
        isElementPresent = driverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(condition)) != null;

        if (isElementPresent)
        {
            singleElement = driver.FindElement(condition);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // log any errors
    }

    return singleElement;
}
```

usages:

```
bool elementExists = _driver.ElementExists(By.Id("submitButton"));

var submitButton = _driver.FindElementAfterWait(By.Id("submitButton"));
submitButton.Click();
_driver.WaitForAjax();

// then do other code stuff...
```

Hopefully, a combo of these may get you out of the fix.

Comment: So what you actually changed is the method you use to wait for element. You use "ExpectedConditions.ElementExists". I'll try it but I doubt that'll work. Thanks for attempt)

Comment: Deni - PLUS, the `WaitForAjax` method loops until the ajax code has completed, or times out after an arbitary time

Comment: Yes.. I have the same code) I think we copied it from the same sours)

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem of working with any asynchronous (AJAX) page.

You don't need to use any "magic" methods like sleeps, jquery.active and expected conditions.

Web pages are usually built that way that user would see when operation ends - like some message appears, or some button become enabled. I believe in your case something like this also happens after you click "Buy Tickets" - you need to notice this and wait for this in your code.

That wait needs to be performed using Explicit wait for your specific case. This is the only reliable way to manage asynchronous pages (including elements not yet clickable).

You can see more detailed overview in my blog post - [Approaches to handling AJAX in Web Automation (Selenium)](https://medium.com/@MrHant/approaches-to-handling-ajax-in-web-automation-selenium-3c44703d02d4)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ElementToBeClickable, try using presenceOfElementLocated. I think your expected element is not present on DOM, so try using presenceOfElementLocated first. Once it is present on DOM, then use ElementToBeClickable.

Comment: I tried the next methods together:

ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy();

ExpectedConditions.ElementExists();

ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected();

ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable();

Comment: I also have the same issue, and not anyone of these helps :(

Comment: None of these conditions (or their combinations) worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

```
 //   public void test() 
   {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ClickSaveButton(driver,"MyButton",10); //Wait for 10 seconds
    }

 //Customized wait block 
public void ClickSaveButton(IWebDriver driver,String ElementID = "" int TimeOut)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Waiting....");
        try
        {
           driver.FindElement(By.Id(ElementID)).Click();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (TimeOut > 0) ClickSaveButton(driver, TimeOut - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem and checking if the element is clickable, visible, located (or their combinations) etc was not enough. Selenium was still not waiting and trying to click on the element.

The only solution I found for my case was a bad practice, but functional as a workaround. I try to get the element inside a Loop with Try/Catch as found here in Falgun Cont response:

[StackExchange - How to wait for element to be clickable in WebDriver with C#](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/how-to-wait-for-element-to-be-clickable-in-webdriver-with-c/20285?newreg=5b025147d25c41fa9d2233de8bf4e634)